# How to apply formating to a region of text over several divs.

Tags: html, parsing, html-parsing

I have the following html.

```
<div>this is line 1 {start-hidden}</div>
<div>this is line 2</div>
<div>{end-hidden} this is line 3</div>
```

I want the text between {start-hidden} and {end-hidden} to be not visible. How can I achieve this? Note that the "start-hidden" and "end-hidden" COULD be in different places. It some extra markup.

Do I need some fancy regex or would it be better to use server side DOM manipulation?

Thanks.

---

**The solution I went with (with PHP) (for those interested):**

Regex to extract all text (+html) inside the {start-hidden} and {end-hidden} [call this part $inner] as well as all the text before [$pre] and after [$post] it.

```
preg_match('#^(.*?){start-hidden}(.*?){end-hidden}(.*?)$#is', $source, $matches)
```

Then remove any cause of new lines within the $inner. Only remove those with closing tags too.

```
// attempt to remove all sources of new lines
$inner = preg_replace('#<br([^>])*>#is', '', $inner);
$inner = preg_replace('#<div([^>])*>(.*?)</div>#is', '', $inner);
$inner = preg_replace('#<p([^>])*>(.*?)</p>#is', '', $inner);
```

Then we find every leftover tag and prefix with </span> and append <span class="hidden">.

```
$inner = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+>)#is', '</span>${1}<span class="hidden">', $inner),
```

Then prefix $inner with <span class="hidden"> and append </span>

```
$inner = '<span class="hidden">' . $inner . '</span>';
```

Finally join it all back together (and repeat if you can preg_match() again).

```
$source  = $pre;
$source .= $inner;
$source .= $post;
```

Comment: Can't you just generate the HTML code in a manner that marks the blocks which can be hidden with divs? Why are you bound to that representation?

Answer (score 1):

Do {start-hidden} and {end-hidden} have to be within the  and  tags as they are?
Adhering to html would suggest using something like (it makes no sense to have styles "break" the div as your suggestion does):

```
<div>this is line 1</div>
<div style="display:none;">this is line 2</div>
<div>this is line 3</div>
```

or, as was suggested by gred:

```
<div>this is line 1</div>
<div style="visibility:hidden;">this is line 2</div>
<div>this is line 3</div>
```

edit: It's important to have a look at the difference between `display:none` and `visibility:hidden`:[w3schools on display vs. visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

Comment: Yes the start-hidden and end-hidden can be anywhere and can have anything inside them. I cannot control the input.

Comment: okay, well as was mentioned to you in your other question on "crossover", what you're trying to do is invalid html. Every html element which is inside of another element needs to have a closing tag before its parent has a closing tag.You're going to need to explain a little better what you're wanting to do with the code. If you know that the {start-hidden} and {end-hidden} will ALWAYS be there, then you should use a span on the part inside the div, as well as make the second div hidden. Otherwise you need to cover those cases in your server-side code.

Comment: I know it invalid HTML so was asking for another solution. I posted a (fairly nasty) solution with regex (see question edit).

Answer (score 0):

Use a span:

```
<div>this is line 1 <span style="visibility:hidden;">{start-hidden}</span></div>
<div>this is line 2</div>
<div><span style="visibility:hidden;">{end-hidden}</span> this is line 3</div>
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted. I need everything BETWEEN the 2 to be hidden. So "this is line 2" should also be hidden.

Comment: Oh... got it! In that case you should try to generate html code with all the hidden part inside a single html element - as others suggest in your question - which is the optimum solution for many reasons OR maybe in my code ALSO add the visibility hidden css style in the second div as well? That maybe would be a little hard to code! - I don't know what kind of technology you are using!